# PHP - Interpret <? as <?php

Tags: php, server

On ours servers are some old scripts which still uses `<?` instead of `<?php` and when I download it to my machine at `localhost` it's not being interpreted, instead it just echoes the code.

Can someone give me a link to a tutorial or tell me how to achive this?

Comment: [short_open_tag](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) setting in your php.ini file

Comment: google little bit a find oneliner script which converts `<? ` to `<?php `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable the `Short tags` in your `php.ini` file like

```
short_open_tag = On
```

And restart your `apache` server.Considering that you have `PHP Version >= 4.0.1`.

Comment: works perfecty, you were the fastest. :)

Answer (score 1):

Set

```
short_open_tag=On
```

in [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

And restart then your Apache server.
The scripts should work then.

Answer (score 0):

set in php.ini and restart server.

```
short_open_tag=On
```

Comment: Your answer would be more useful if you edit it to explain what it does an why it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
short_open_tag=On
in php.ini
```

> And restart your Apache server.